# Prevent Visual Studio from indenting code after multi-line template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have recently discovered that Visual Studio likes to indent things after a template which takes up multiple lines, as you can see here:
[image: indented class declaration]
After the template, in which I like to list parameters on different lines to prevent one huge line, the class declaration is indented by a tab. It indents *the whole class declaration*, so possibly hundreds of lines end up indented unnecessarily.

This happens every time I use Visual Studio's auto formatting tool, which is rather annoying, as I do want to be able to use auto format (it's very helpful), but just not this specific "feature"(?). I've looked through all the options in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting, but I have not managed to find one that fixes this issue.

**How can I prevent Visual Studio from indenting code after multi-line templates like this?**

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you talking about? I just tried this with VS 2019 and it does not ident the class.

Comment: @Hajo VS2019 (16.11.5): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNpYb.png, it only occurs when nested, not at the top level, so when in a class, struct, namespace etc.

Comment: I'm surprised that Visual Studio still has this issue. Shortly after I asked this question I abandoned the hope of autoformatters working correctly for C++...

Comment: Hm, fascinating. Indeed only in a namespace. I can confirm that this is still the case with VS2022. I guess one could create/edit a clangformat file but this really should work out of the box :)